# Copying a foreign key value in an row generation trigger

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I'm trying to build a trigger that will auto-fill information into tblRegistrations when a new entry is created in tblAttendees and I'm unsure what I should be using to get it to take the new Auto-incremented key from the tblAttendees?

So in the code Registration ID is the primary key auto_incremented for tblRegistrations and AttendeeID is the primary key auto_incremented for tblattendees which exists as a foreign key on tblRegistrations

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgRegistration 
AFTER INSERT ON tblattendees 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tblregistration (RegistrationID, AttendeeID, EventID, RegistrationDate, RegistrationPaid) 
VALUES (AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT, '3', CURRENT_DATE, '0')
```

When I try to end a new entry into the attendees table to test the trigger I keep getting this error:

"#1054- Unknown Column 'Auto_Increment' in 'field list'

Clearly it's a problem with how I have by Values formatted, but I'm uncertain on how to proceed.

Comment: 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger' , 'In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column `RegistrationID` should take care of itself if you put `NULL` there or just leave it out of the column list.

As for the newly-generated `AttendeeID`, you can access that using the `NEW` keyword, which stands for the newly-inserted row that caused the trigger to run.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trgRegistration 
AFTER INSERT ON tblattendees 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tblregistrations (AttendeeID, EventID, RegistrationDate, RegistrationPaid)
VALUES (NEW.AttendeeID, '3', CURRENT_DATE, '0');
```